# Фильтрация по нескольким таксономиям и пагинация?

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

Сейчас у меня выводятся кастомные программы в functions следующим образом:

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function'); // wp_ajax_{ACTION HERE} 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');

function misha_filter_function(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
        'order' => $_POST['date'] // ASC or DESC
    );

    // for taxonomies / categories
    if( isset( $_POST['level'] ) )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'level',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['level']
            )
        );
        
    

    // create $args['meta_query'] array if one of the following fields is filled
    if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] || isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] || isset( $_POST['featured_image'] ) && $_POST['featured_image'] == 'on' )
        $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' ); // AND means that all conditions of meta_query should be true

    // if both minimum price and maximum price are specified we will use BETWEEN comparison
    if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] && isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => array( $_POST['price_min'], $_POST['price_max'] ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'between'
        );
    } else {
        // if only min price is set
        if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => $_POST['price_min'],
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>'
            );

        // if only max price is set
        if( isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => '_price',
                'value' => $_POST['price_max'],
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '<'
            );
    }


    // if post thumbnail is set
    if( isset( $_POST['featured_image'] ) && $_POST['featured_image'] == 'on' )
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        );
    // if you want to use multiple checkboxed, just duplicate the above 5 lines for each checkbox

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="card-item">
                <!-- какой-то контент -->
            </div>
            <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else : ?>
        <div class="card-no-result">
            <h2>Нет подходящей программы?</h2>
            <p>Напишите нам об этом и мы придумаем для вас индивидуальное  решение.</p>
            <a class="btn popup-call" href="#modal">Получить решение</a>
        </div> 
        <?php
    endif;


    die();
}
```

Форма (не вся, потому что займёт много места, там повторяются таксономии) с помощью которой мы выбираем нужную таксономию и после нажатия выполняется код в functions:

```
        <form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
        <div class="simple-filter_item button-group filters">
            <p class="rus">Уровень подготовки</p>
            <?php
            $categories = get_terms('level', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0');
            if($categories){
                echo '<select name="level" id="level1"><option value="card-item">Любой</option>';
                foreach ($categories as $cat){
                    echo "<option value='{$cat->term_id}'>{$cat->name}</option>";
                }
                echo '</select>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="simple-filter_item">
            <p>Направление образования</p>
            <?php
                $categories = get_terms('direction', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0');
                if($categories){
                    echo '<select name="direction" id="direction1"><option value="card-item">Любое</option>';
                    foreach ($categories as $cat){
                        echo "<option value='direction-{$cat->term_id}'>{$cat->name}</option>";
                    }
                    echo '</select>';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="filter-button filter-disactive">
            <div class="simple-btn">
                <button class="btn_access func-during">Подобрать</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Ну и скрипт с помощью которого я могу указать, что после нажатия на кнопку форма должна обрабатываться и выводится в необходимом div с id = card-wrapper-first:

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
$("#filter").submit(function () {
  var filter = $("#filter");
  $.ajax({
    url: filter.attr("action"),
    data: filter.serialize(), // form data
    type: filter.attr("method"), // POST
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      filter.find("button").text("Processing..."); // changing the button label
    },
    success: function (data) {
      filter.find("button").text("Подобрать"); // changing the button label back
      $("#card-wrapper-first").html(data); // insert data
    },
  });
  return false;
});
```

});

**Вывод пагинации идёт сразу после вывода всех программ:**

```
<?php  $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=program-card' ); ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts()):$query->the_post(); ?>
   <div class="card-item">
       <!-- Какой-то контент... -->
   </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php kama_pagenavi($before = '', $after = '', $echo = true, $args = array(), 
$wp_query = $query); ?>
```

Подведём итоги из всего: **как можно переделать функцию из functions.php, чтобы фильтровались программы не с помощью одной таксономии (уровень подготовки), а с учётом и других тоже (указал здесь только 2, но на деле их 5). И как мне сделать пагинацию, чтобы они выводились не все разом, потому что их может быть более 200, а только по 30 на одной странице**

**Заранее огромное спасибо за ваше терпение и помощь!**

Comment: Где вывод пагинации то?)

Comment: @WPPunk Извиняюсь, был уверен, что добавил, но не перечитал всё. Дополнил ответ)