# Почему не рaботает пагинация?

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование

Выводится пагинация на кастомный пост. Сам кастомный пост с пагинацией ниже выводится так:

```
 <?php  $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=program-card' ); ?>
 <?php while ( $query->have_posts()):$query->the_post(); ?>
 <div class="card-item">
    <!---------
     Какой-то контент...
   ---------->
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php kama_pagenavi($before = '', $after = '', $echo = true, $args = array(), $wp_query = $query); ?>
```

Выведем пагинатор. Предпочитаю использовать кастомный пагинатор Камы. С сайта wp-kama.ru. Добавил нижеприведенный код в functions.php. С этим проблем точно не должно быть, всё-таки wp-kama говна не даст)
http://wp-kama.ru/?p=8 (скопировал самый первый код полностью до "else return $out;")

Ну и сам код кастомного поста:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {
 $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $args = array(
   'label'                 => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
   'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
   'labels'                => $labels,
   'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
   'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
   'hierarchical'          => false,
   'public'                => true,
   'show_ui'               => true,
   'show_in_menu'          => true,
   'menu_position'         => 20,
   'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
   'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
   'can_export'            => true,
   'has_archive'           => true,
   'exclude_from_search'   => false,
   'publicly_queryable'    => true,
   'capability_type'       => 'page',
   'posts_per_page' => 25,
   'post_type'      => 'offers',
   'orderby'        => 'date',
   'order'          => 'DESC',
   'paged'          => $paged
 );
 register_post_type( 'program-card', $args );
```

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );

Сама пагинация выводится отлично, подсчёт страниц делается верно. Когда кликаю по ссылке(какая-то страница), то в адресную строку добавляется /page/6(любая другая стр.), но посты не меняются. Активная страница остаётся так же первой, как и до клика, хотя в адресную строку всё добавляется. Может я где-то не так вставил или что-то впереди другого, вроде все варианты перепробовал, но, видимо, что-то упустил.

P.S. в постоянных ссылках если что стоит пункт "Название записи", если это вдруг что-то значит

Answer (score 1):

Вы функцию используете как-то не так :)

```
kama_pagenavi( [], $query );
```

Comment: Где она должна стоять у кастомного вывода поста?

<?php  $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=program-card' ); ?>

<?php while ( $query->have_posts()):$query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="card-item">

 <!-- Какой-то контент... -->

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

Comment: И не могли бы ответить тут?:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154791/Фильтрация-по-нескольким-таксономиям-и-пагинация  Как фильтровать не по одной таксономии, а по нескольким?

Comment: @Рома первый аргумент функции это параметры разные. 2-й это query для которого вы делаете пагинацию. Если вы делаете $q = new WP_Query(), тогда второй параметр $q